# Semaphores waiting for child threads

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, posix, semaphore, condition-variable

I was reading some code for an exam, and it is something like:

```
sem_t s;

int main(int argc ,char *argv[]) {
    thread_t p1, p2, p3;

    sem_init(&s,X,X)

    thread_create(&p1,child);
    thread_create(&p2,child);

    thread_create(&p3,child);

    sem wait(&s);
}
```

How should I initialize semaphore `s`, assuming that every thread in child has a `sem_post()` on `s`, so that the parent concludes his run after three children?

I would say I should initialize it as "`sem_init(&s, 1, -2)`" so that the 3 `sem_post`s take it to 1 and the `sem_wait` doesn't put it to sleep, but still, I think that `sem_post` wakes a thread up even if the value of the semaphore is less than 0, so, if the parent goes on wait, then the first child to do a `sem_post` wakes him up and it does not wait for all three children.

I was reading *Operating Systems - Three Easy Pieces*, and in the concurrency part, when talking about semaphores it does not say that if the value of a semaphore is less than 0 after the increment of a `sem_post` it does not wake up a thread that is already on a `sem_wait`, so I assume it in fact does wake it up in any case.

Comment: There is an essential detail of semaphore semantics that you are overlooking: their values can never be less than 0.  This is so fundamental that it's not uncommon for documentation to take it as given, but see [`sem_overview(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html).  I think you will see, then, that your proposed strategy will not work, and your questions about the behavior of `sem_post()` are moot.

Comment: Does [pthread_join](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) fit your use case?  SysV ("XSI") semaphores — complex and awkward to use — support the concept of ["waiting for zero,"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/semop.html) meaning _main_ could initialize the sem to 3 and awaken after all three children decrement (wait) the sem.  POSIX [barriers](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_barrier_wait.html) could serve a similar purpose.  You could do it yourself with condition variables, of course.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I initialize semaphore `s`, assuming that every thread in `child` has a `sem_post()` on `s`, so that the parent concludes his run after three children?

There is no way to initialize `s` that guarantees such behavior from the given `main()`, no matter what the behavior of `child()`.  You cannot initialize `s` to a value less than 0.  If you initialize it to a value greater than zero then `main()`'s single `sem_wait()` does not have to wait for any of the children at all.  If you initialize it to 0 then `main()` can proceed as soon as any one of the children performs a `sem_post()`.

If you want `main()` to wait for all three children, each of which increments the semaphore exactly once and never decrements it, then the semaphore must be initialized to 0 **and** `main` must `sem_wait()` three times.